# Override WordPress media manager hook

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am creating a WordPress plugin and am trying to overwrite the following value in javascript:

`'query-attachments'` within [/wp-includes/js/media-models.js around line 1086](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/js/media-models.js#L1086).

However the issue the I am having is I cannot seem to figure out where I can change the `options` parameter within the `sync` function, where from there I can change the `action` value?